# PHP cURL connection refused while using proxy

Tags: php, curl

I am getting this error in my PHP cURL

> Failed to connect to ip port after 1000 ms: Connection refused

I have this code:

```php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'ip'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 'port');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,'user:pass');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   die(curl_error($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
```

I don't know why I am having this error.

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Was the proxy running on the local host? Is it running on the server? If not can the server get to the proxy?

Comment: didn't tried on localhost i'm on shared hosting where i'm testing the script.

Comment: Where is the proxy located?

Comment: i have proxy from webshare site which I'm using for the curl request.

Comment: Is that the same as your web host?

Comment: no both are different as web host is namecheap and proxy is from webshare.

Comment: To me it looks like a networking problem. One or both sites cannot access the other.You need to talk to your providers.

Comment: Okay! you mean above is perfectly correct? The problem will be with web host?

Comment: Looks good. Especially if it worked on a different machine. One other thing you can do is set CURLOPT_VERBOSE to true to get more detail.